# Best way to build case logic into SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design, view

I'm looking to build some logic into a SQL view and I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this. Basically I have a  SQL view and it needs to look at `[sender_city]` and `[receiver_city]` to determine `[Division]`. I think this needs to be a case statement??

I'll have a table to reference `[Division]`:

```
[Location]   [Division]
Location_1   Division_X
Location_2   Division_X
Location_3   Division_X
Location_4   Division_Y
Location_5   Division_Z
```

This is my best attempt to describe the logic needed (sudocode):

```
If [sender_city] = [Location], then display [Division] 
else if [receiver_city] = [Location], then display [Division] 
else "Other Division"
```

I also need to build in some logic where if both `[sender_city]` and `[receiver_city]` reference a division, it needs to just use the `[sender_city]` division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to LEFT JOIN to the Division table twice, once for the sender and once for the receiver. The COALESCE will return the first non-null value and will also handle your rule that sender takes priority over receiver when determining division.

```
SELECT COALESCE(d1.Division, d2.Division, 'Other Division') AS Division
    FROM SomeTable st
        LEFT JOIN Divsion d1
           ON st.sender_city = d1.Location
        LEFT JOIN Division d2
           ON st.receiver_city = d2.location
```

Comment: Joe this was exactly what I was looking for. I have a second issue that I've discovered now where it's not capturing all sender cities and receiver cities. For example, some are listed as "New York City NY" or "San Francisco CA". It is classifying these locations as 'Other Division'. Is there any way to match these instances?

Comment: @user2860150 If those exact values don't exist in your Division table, then there's no way to work around it.

Comment: Hmm okay not a huge problem then, but could we somehow incorporate a % wildcard? where it finds a location that begins with the matching portion from my SomeTable?

Comment: You could write functions to compare the names that build in as much legal variation as you want. Most flavors of SQL have provisions for writing user-defined functions that can do character manipulation. But you're going to quickly get into complex questions about defining what constitutes a "match" if it's not "identical strings". Intuitively, "New York City", "New York", "NYC", and "The Big Apple" are all the same place. But unless you make a list of alternative names, how would the computer know that "NYC" stands for "New York City" and not, say, "Northern Yaron County" (a real place)?

Comment: @Jay thanks for your response. I developed a workaround by defining these instances in my Division table. I was able to capture all of these instances but I'll just have to revisit this process every month or so to define any additional new instances in my table that I didn't capture with my data set.